# WordPress Ajax strange print

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

I have an ajax issue on WordPress. I have a simple Select with a button which has an onclick function which works with ajax.

That function, which calls a file named ajax-filter-system.php that has a simple string "HELLO WORLD", reload the div content with class 'ajax-loader', print 'HELLO WORD0' with '0' at the end of string. Can't understand why...

Function.php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_load_specialita', 'load_specialita_ajax_handler');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_specialita', 'load_specialita_ajax_handler');
function load_specialita_ajax_handler() {
    require(get_stylesheet_directory().'/assets/ajax/ajax-filter-system.php'); 
}
```

ajax-filter-system.php

```
<div>Hello World</div>
```

Function onclick (js file)

```
function showSpecialita() {
jQuery(function($) {
    var select_target = "";
    var select_target = $('#specialita-selected').val(); // <select> ID

    var xhttp;
    $.ajax({
        url : 'https://www.mysite.it/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', // AJAX handler
        data : { action : 'load_specialita', specialita : select_target },
        type : 'POST',
        success : function( result ){
            if( result ) {
                $('.ajax-loader-specialita').html(result);
            }
        }
    });
});
}
```

If I change

```
$('.ajax-loader-specialita').html(result);
```

in

```
$('.ajax-loader-specialita').html('Hello Word');
```

it works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed `exit` in end of the function.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_load_specialita', 'load_specialita_ajax_handler');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_specialita', 'load_specialita_ajax_handler');
function load_specialita_ajax_handler() {
    require(get_stylesheet_directory().'/assets/ajax/ajax-filter-system.php'); 
    exit;
}
```

Comment: i will but i can in 9 minute